# What are the values in brackets under the estimators value representing?

Tags: econometrics, regression, statistics

[image: ** What does the values in red circles represent?**]

Please, can you explain me what are these values in red circles representing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are most likely [standard errors of the estimates](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/standard-error-of-estimate#:%7E:text=The%20standard%20error%20of%20estimate%2C%20Se%20indicates%20approximately%20how,the%20actual%20value%20of%20Y.), it is a convention in some subfields of economics to report standard errors in brackets under the mean estimates in brackets.

Comment: Sometimes they are t-statistics, but this particular example has magnitudes that suggest they are indeed standard errors.